# Implement endless RecyclerView with control for max elements in memory (ArrayList)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, endlessscroll

**Task:**

1) Read data from SQLITE (1000 elements) by 20 elements

2) set Max size for ArrayList (50 for example)

3) Scroll down - load more items and remove invisible items from
            ArrayList

4) Scroll up - load prev items and remove invisible items from
            ArrayList

5) Scroll bar corresponds to the number of records in the db

When `List size > Max_elements_in_memory` I try to remove items from ArrayList if it invisible for user. But my RecyclerView ends on 120 position.How to resolve it task ? Thanks

**EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener**

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;

    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;

    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;

    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;

    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {

        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {

        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {

        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();

    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {

        int maxSize = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }

            else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {

        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {

            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);

            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);

        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {

            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

        }

        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state

        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {

            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;

            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }

        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.

        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too

        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {

            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Call this method whenever performing new searches
    public void resetState() {

        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        this.loading = true;
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static int DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_MEMORY = 50;
    private static int DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW = 20;
    private int from = 0;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_view)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private UsersAdapter usersAdapter;
    private List<User> usersList;

    // Store a member variable for the listener
    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        res = getResources();

        usersList = new ArrayList<>();
        usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(this, usersList);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        } else{
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        }

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {

                loadNextDataFromDb(page);
            }
        };
        // Adds the scroll listener to RecyclerView
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.users_loader, Bundle.EMPTY, this);

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.users_loader:
                return new UsersLoader(this, from, DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW);

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        int id = loader.getId();

        if (usersList.size() > 0)
        if (usersList.size() - DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW > DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_MEMORY) {
            for (int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW; i++) {
                usersList.remove(i);
            }
            /*usersList.clear();
            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            scrollListener.resetState();*/
        }
            usersList.addAll((List) UsersTable.listFromCursor(data));
            usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    private void loadNextDataFromDb(int offset) {
        from = offset * DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS_IN_RECYCLER_VIEW;
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(R.id.users_loader, Bundle.EMPTY, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Recyclerview recycles invisible views by default.

Comment: This is my test task from company. As I think, it need if we have a very big data in ArrayList. If user scrolled down a several thousands position we don't need invisible elements. Our heap size will be so large. There is no good. I think you understand it too. But first of all, this is to check how man will seek a solution to this problem.